# Site not accessible by public IP address

Tags: iis, server, windows-server, iis-10, windows-server-2019

I have a site example.com on a server with public IP 12.345.678.90
when I hit the site with domain it works fine but I want it to be also accessible if I hit https://12.345.678.90

Is it possible?

I am getting this if hit URL in browser.
[image]

Comment: Perfectly normal if your site bindings mandate that, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background

Comment: Could you please inform us whether you are using on-prem Win Server 2019 OS or is it Azure VM? What are the site bindings for the site? Are you using other ports except default ports? You may need to allow ports in the firewall rule. Further, in the site bindings, add a new binding and keep the IP address unassigned and Host name empty. Try to access the site using IP and see if you could visit the site.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Its on premises win server 2019, there are 3 sites hosted on the server. Bindings are 80 and  443. I tried with different ports and allowed them in firewall but it did not work.

Comment: Could you please share what do you see in browser when you access the site with the IP address? Are other sites having bindings with the IP and same port you use for this site? If you visit using HTTP protocol, does it work? Make sure to keep the IP as unassigned and Hostname empty.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT, I attached the screen shot in my question. there are other sites as well on the server using same port (443) for https bindings. http doesn't  work as port 80 is not opened for the security reasons.

Comment: @WSk, for testing purposes, try to use different port for HTTPS and use your IP address to visit the site and see if it reaches to your site? You need to open that port in the firewall.